# Simulate keypress javascript NO JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, web

I have a webgame I made in pure javascript using processing.js
It works fine on desktop but I want it to work on mobile. 
It's on this website: https://www.ricarddokifuri.tk/mlg/

I found a function to detect swipes

```
function swipedetect(el, callback){

var touchsurface = el,
swipedir,
startX,
startY,
distX,
distY,
threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
allowedTime = 300, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
elapsedTime,
startTime,
handleswipe = callback || function(swipedir){}

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
    swipedir = 'none'
    dist = 0
    startX = touchobj.pageX
    startY = touchobj.pageY
    startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
    e.preventDefault()
}, false)

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
}, false)

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
    distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
    if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for awipe met
        if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
            swipedir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates left swipe
        }
        else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
            swipedir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
        }
    }
    handleswipe(swipedir)
    e.preventDefault()
}, false)
```

}

I can activate  and detect which direction was swiped like this

```
swipedetect(el, function(swipedir){
if (swipedir == 'left')
    alert('You just swiped left!')
});
```

My function  to move the player is like this

```
var movePlayer = function(){
if(keyCode === LEFT){
    x -= 3.5*scaless;
}
if(keyCode === RIGHT){
    x += 3.5*scaless;
}
if(keyCode === UP){
    y -= 3.5*scaless;
}  
if(keyCode === DOWN){
    y += 3.5*scaless;
}
};
if(keyPressed){
    movePlayer();
}
```

How could I make the function that detects a swipe, simulate a keypress?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your movePlayer function both for the keyboard and for swipes, then I would probably make it accept an argument and then call it either from a keypress event handler with the event keycode either from the swipe handler with an appropriate argument.

So basically, according to this: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

The keycodes for up,right,down,left are:

UP: 38
RIGHT: 39
DOWN: 40
LEFT: 37

so you could modify your move player like so:

```
var movePlayer = function(keyCode){
    if(keyCode === LEFT){
       x -= 3.5*scaless;
    }
    if(keyCode === RIGHT){
       x += 3.5*scaless;
    }
    if(keyCode === UP){
       y -= 3.5*scaless;
    }  
    if(keyCode === DOWN){
       y += 3.5*scaless;
    }
};
```

From your code snippet, I am assuming that LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN are constant values, somewhere else in your program, so then I would modify my swipe detect function like:

```
swipedetect(el, function(swipedir){
  if (swipedir == 'left'){
    movePlayer(LEFT);
  }else if(swipedir == 'right'){
    movePlayer(RIGHT);
  }else if(swipedir == 'up'){
    movePlayer(UP);
  }else if(swipedir == 'down'){
    movePlayer(DOWN);
  }
  //you can have the default case in an else here
});
```

Then, you would need to modify the keypress code that calls movePlayer when the user uses the keyboard to pass the code of the key that was pressed i.e. by doing  movePlayer(event.keyCode) in your keypress event handler.

Comment: This kind of works. If you go on your phone to [the game](https://www.ricardokifuri.tk/mlg/mobile.html) The swipes move the player in an odd way. It's because the function movePlayer(); is not being called continuously. That's why I want a way to simulate a key press. https://www.ricardokifuri.tk/mlg/cubeDodgerM.js is the link to the game's main JavaScript

Comment: @RicardoKifuri you are correct. This is because your swipedetect doesn't throw swipe events continuously, whereas a keypress would do as long as you kept your finger on the button.

I suppose if you changed move player to add a second argument, you can call movePlayer(LEFT, 10) for example from swipedetect and movePlayer(LEFT,1) from they keypress listener and then in your movePlayer that is going to look like movePlayer(keyCode, multiplier) if the move is LEFT for example you could do,x-=3.5*scaless*multiplier; 
Then experiment with the multiplier until you find a good value.

Comment: It won't be that good though cause it will look like the player kinda jumps from one place to another with swipe. Another solution would be to call moveplayer inside a loop from your swipedetect function with some sort of delay between the calls so that the player kinda looks like it's moving. This will be a bit heavy on performance I am assuming though...

Comment: @kilkas `if(keyPressed){
  movePlayer();
 }` Triggers movePlayer(); And it doesn't stop even after you let go, I need swipedetect to be like that. I don't know of any way to do so.  The swipe moves it too far. Swipedetect does x+=3.5*scaless to many times. It should only do it 50 times a second.

Comment: @RicardoKifuri what I was trying to say with my answer is that you need to find a way to simulate keypress events when the user swipes. 
The initial solution didn't work cause keypress event fire multiple times when your finger presses the arrow buttons, whereas swipe, fires only once when your finger ends the touch action. So after the touch action, you should try to run movePlayer in a loop, to simulate keypress firing multiple times. You should do it with a slight delay between the calls though to make the player look like it is moving, rather than look like it is jumping on the screen.